# Retrieving all posts by liked post's tags

Tags: python, html, django, tags

I am trying to implement a feature in my Social Media WebApp . I am trying to get all tags posts according to user's liked posts

*For Example ( In Brief ) :-*

> Suppose, `user_1` liked a `post` and that post contains `tags of` #tag1 , #tag2 , #tag3. AND i am trying to show all the posts in a page that contains one of these tags which is liked by user.

models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='post_like', blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

views.py

```
def get_post(request,user_id):
    tags = Tag.objects.filter(post=id)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(likes__in=[user_id])

    context = {'posts':posts,'tagss':tagss}
    return render(request,'like_post.html', context)
```

like_post.html

```
{% for post in posts %}


{% for tag in post.tags.all %}

{{ tag }}

{% endfor %}


{% endfor %}
```

When i try to run this in browser then it only shows the posts done by me and its tags.

**What have i tried :-**

- I tried also by `i_contains=tags` but this didn't worked for me.
- I noticed a question yesterday about it BUT that question is deleted too.
- I also tried this :-

  ```
    def get_like_related_post(request,user_id):
        post = get_object_or_404(Post,post_owner=user_id)
        posts = Tag.objects.filter(tag_id_in=post.likes.all)
  ```

BUT it is keep showing

> **get() returned more than one Post -- it returned 6!**

I am new in Django AND I have no idea , how can i do it.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance

Comment: can you show the lilke model?. If you have everything else setup correctly, both`Post.objects.filter(likes__id=user_id)` or `Like.objects.filter(user__in=[user_id]` should do the work for you.

Comment: I don't have `likes model` likes instance is in the `Post Model`

Comment: @Abhyudai, According to your suggestion, It will only `get posts which are created by me`. BUT i am trying to `get posts by all tags which is liked by user` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try filtering on `taggit.models.Tag` to get the tags that are related to posts liked by the user and then filtering the posts on those tags. Which will be something like (Untested):

```py
from taggit.models import Tag


def get_post(request,user_id):
    tags = Tag.objects.filter(post__likes=user_id).distinct()
    posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__in=tags).distinct()
    context = {'posts':posts,'tags':tags}
    return render(request,'like_post.html', context)
```